# What do we call the PDE problems in the form of $\Delta u + \epsilon u = f$ on Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

I'm studying the existence and uniqueness of a solution and its asymptotic behaviour to the following problem

\begin{align}
& -\Delta u +\epsilon u = f \text{  on }  \Omega \\
& \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}= g \text{ on } \Gamma
\end{align}

through variational formulations and Sobolev spaces.

Where $\Omega$ is the domain, $\Gamma$ its border and $\epsilon > 0$.

Does anyone know where I can find resources for this type of problem ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know any references that tackle the case with Neumann boundary conditions with much detail, but this type of equation is known as an elliptic PDE and there are a ton of very approachable results out there for these types of equations. Check out Chapter 6 of Evans' book and Chapter 7 of Taylor's first book for some results and references.

Comment: @whpowell96 will do, thanks !